# mysql query not returning correct percentage

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I am trying to get select results, with a date clause. Group by column, count the total of another column and then work out the percentage of that count associated with the grouped column.

ID | Delaytype | Delayhours |Delaydate

1  | type1   |       2     |   2015-01-10

2  | type2    |     3      |   2015-01-10

3  |type2     |     1      |   2015-02-10

4  | type2    |      1     |  2015-01-10

So a Query on the month of Jan should give me : 
type 1 = 33.3%
type 2 = 66.6%

My query so far is :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Delaytype, SUM(`Delayhours`) / (SELECT Sum(Delayhours)) 
        * 100 as cnt FROM delays  WHERE YEAR(Delaydate) = '".$yearly."' AND MONTH(Delaydate) = '".$month."' GROUP BY Delaytype; ");
```

However I am getting a 100% result for each Delaytype

thankyou in advance for any help.

Cant see where I can make a table so I apologize for the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DelayType,
    SUM(Delayhours) AS Delaytotal,
    ROUND(
        100*(
          SUM(Delayhours) / 
          (
              SELECT SUM(Delayhours) 
              FROM dummy 
              WHERE 
                  Delaydate >= '2015-01-01' AND
                  Delaydate < '2015-02-01'
          )
        ), 
        2
    ) AS Delaypercents
FROM dummy
WHERE 
    Delaydate >= '2015-01-01' AND 
    Delaydate < '2015-02-01'
GROUP BY Delaytype
```

[And catch the fiddle :)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/792e2/8)

P.S. Thanks to Used_By_Already for new details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works better than mine but I get a discrepancy when checking. so if results are 10,7,3,3,10 i am getting 34.29%, 20.00%, 8.57%, 8.57%, 28.57%. Also it does not apply the date rule. I want only from jan in the example above.

Comment: @userlond look  here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/792e2/8 it's just a mater of using where clauses in both the outer and subquery `where Delaydate >= '2015-01-01' and Delaydate < '2015-02-01'` but PLEASE do NOT use `between`

Comment: @userlord  thank you I missed the where statement number 1. Working fine now. Was getting the error because it was returning the percentage from the whole table not the month of Jan. Many thanks.